# What is a C++ implementation or analogue of the local peak detector skimage.feature.peak_local_max?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image, watershed

I need to find local peaks on the depth image to generate the markers for a watershed algorithm in C++.

My Python implementation uses **skimage.feature.peak_local_max** to generate the markers for a watershed algorithm.

Can't find a **C++ implementation** or **C++ analogue** of the **skimage.feature.peak_local_max** function.

Some algorithm to find a local maximum for a matrix also could be helpful.

```
distance = scipy.ndimage.distance_transform_edt(image)
local_maxi = skimage.feature.peak_local_max(distance, indices=False, footprint=np.ones((3, 3)), labels=image)
markers = scipy.ndimage.label(local_maxi)[0]
labels = skimage.segmentation.watershed(-distance, markers, mask=image)
```

[Example of the peak finder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyruA.png)

Any ideas on C++ implementation of the local peak finder, please? Thank you!

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for this function? It says “Locations where the original image is equal to the dilated image are returned as local maxima.” There’s your algorithm.

Comment: Thanks, @CrisLuengo! It is theoretically indeed could be represented as comparison of dilated image with original image. In the Python implementation maximum_filter is used as dilation to produce peak candidates.
[link] (https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/bd4b3d4f137243b85221280f3061837c97d66a50/skimage/feature/peak.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a pure C++ implementation, I would suggest taking a look at ITK. The `RegionalMaximalImageFilter` class from ITK will produce a binary image with the foreground representing local maxima. It even works for "flat" regions where the local maximum is constant. This link shows an example: [RegionalMaximal](https://itk.org/ITKExamples/src/Filtering/MathematicalMorphology/RegionalMaximal/Documentation.html)

Original Image:

[image: Original Image]

Local Maxima Image:

[image: Local Maxima]